# how to edit header using html js and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I need to do same header as this one :
[Final result I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKncZ.png)

this is my initial code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Site web </title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
  </style>
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-12">
      <img src="plante.png" style="width:30px" />
      <div>Les jardins du lys </div>
      <div style="text-align: center">
        ACCUEIL • CREATION DE JARDIN • ENTRETIEN DE JARDIN • CONTACT
      </div>
      <div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

please if you have any idea how to edit this page

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of things you have to change in order to reach your goal. The first thing you should take a look at is maybe, to take a look at the code of the final result, you are aiming for. Just go to the site where the final result header is, and open developer tools and look at the code. And try to understand which part is used for which part. Firstly you need to build a full functioning page - as an example, your menu items are plain text, which means, when clicking them, notihing will happen. You have to transform them into links, for instance. When everything works, you can start with the CSS styling.

Good luck!